# Continuously update UISlider within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uislider

I'm looking to use a UISlider as an "Audio VU Meter" type indicator, where an audio track's level continuously updates the value of the UISlider. Each track in my application is currently situated as a UITableViewCell, with the VU Meter being one subview within the cell's content view. As many as 12 tracks are displayed at a time.

The updates to the VU meter are coming via a TCP/IP port, so once I receive the new VU level and set the fader value (`mySlider.value = newValue`). However, the only way I can get the slider to update immediately is by calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:myTableView waitUntilDone:NO`. Seems like I shouldn't have to reload the entire table's data.

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TrackTableCell *cell = (TrackTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrackTableCell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TrackTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [self trackTableCell];

        /**************************/
        /********* FADER  *********/
        /**************************/
        VolumeSlider *fader = [[VolumeSlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 265, 30)];
        [fader setRotatedThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FaderCap.png"]];
        [fader setRotatedMinTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeSlider.png"]];
        [fader setRotatedMaxTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VolumeSlider.png"]];

        [fader addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeFaderSliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        fader.value = 0;

        // rotate the slider
        fader.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:fader];

        fader.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 265, 30);
        fader.center = CGPointMake(70, 515);

        // property of the cell
        cell.volumeSlider = fader;
    }


    // set the slider to 0
    cell.volumeSlider.value = [[self.tracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] volume];

    return cell;
}
```

The following method is called via a notification that the data model (`[[tracks objectAtIndex:trackNumber] volume]`) has been updated.

```
- (void) updateVolumeFader:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSDictionary *extraInfo = [note userInfo];
    int trackNumber = [[extraInfo objectForKey:@"trackNumber"] intValue];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:trackNumber inSection:0];

    TrackTableCell *cell = (TrackTableCell *)[self.tracksTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.volumeSlider.value = [[tracks objectAtIndex:trackNumber] volume]; 
}
```

In reviewing the code, my guess is it's in the way I'm obtaining the cell pointer. I'm guessing calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not the best way. Further, I am just now realizing that calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in itself should update the fader to the new value, in the `tracks` array.

As has been suggested perhaps it's best to keep a cached array of all of my tracks' sliders (or all of my cells, for that matter). While this is certainly not the most efficient code, I still don't understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why not just refresh the slider value for the visible cells rather than reload the whole table? Is the slider a property on the cells?

Comment: Yes, the slider value is a property on the cell. However, when updating the property, the displayed value of the UISlider is not updated until reloadData is called on the main thread. Further, AFAIK, reloadData simply calls cellForRowAtIndexPath on indexPath's that are currently visible.

Comment: So if you update the slider value when you set the slider value property, does that improve things?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure I follow what you mean by "update the slider value when you set the slider value property"? That is how I'm updating the slider value, by calling myTableCell.mySlider.value. Doing this doesn't cause the slider to immediately update it's position. To do that I have to call reloadData on the tableView (on the main thread).

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the interface of your cell. If the slider is a public property, then what happens if you do something like iterate `[self.tableView visibleCells]` and for each cell set the new slider value? Does that have a difference as compared to reloading the table view?

Comment: I could try it, but I think the root of the issue is that no matter how I get the reference to the cell of interest, setting the slider's value property will not cause the display of the slider's position to update. To get it to visually update, I need to call reloadData (or do something like scroll the view), which causes the tableView to decide it needs to update the position.

Comment: I did make a sample project to do exactly this before suggesting it, so I'm not sure what you're doing that prevents updating the UI of visible cells unless the table view scrolls. Can you elaborate about that?

Comment: To reiterate what @CarlVeazey said, you do NOT need to reload the table - so something you are doing now is a problem. That said, are your cells static or recycled? If you don't have too many rows (say less than 20) make the cells static. If you must recycle, then create a slider for each indexPath, save them in an array, keep their values up to date, then add them back into the proper cell during recycle or create new action. Keep saying this to yourself - "I do not need to reload the data - I do not need to ...." :-)

Comment: Ok... this is good news. I struggled for hours last night trying to get the slider to update at all (as I didn't think I needed to reload either), until I found that reloading the data on the main thread did it. Looks like this was just a workaround for a larger issue. My cells are recycled -- I will try setting them up as static. But, there must me something else I'm doing wrong as well, because even when I attempt to update the slider value for a cell that is plainly visible (and therefore having nothing to do with the recycling in cellForRowAtIndexPath), the slider still doesn't move.

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to do that?

Comment: Yeah sorry I would have done so by now but it's not with me at the moment -- will have to post it later tonight. Thanks for the patience/help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your notifications are not coming through on the main thread, your code to update the slider won't work. The code in your notification method is otherwise fine; simply place it inside a block and execute on the main thread, or register on the main thread (operation queue) when you register for the notification.

Comment: Awesome! Running a block on main thread did the trick. As an extension to the question, in a recycled table cell case (as I'm using), is there a better way to obtain the appropriate cell pointer than calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: No, that's the best way. If you do that, and the cell is off the screen, it returns nil so you don't waste any time updating it.

Comment: Note there's a difference between asking the _table_ for cellForRowAtIndexPath, and asking the _datasource_ for it. The datasource one is the method you write yourself (but don't call yourself). Asking the table for a cell does not hit the datasource.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks for that distinction. A very important one that I didn't understand. Perfect! Thanks for your great help! :)